# Windows XP SP3: browser timeouts sometimes

Tags: networking, windows-xp

I have a good internet connection. I connect to the router directly (UTP). If I start an infinitive ping, it always answers, no timeouts. Now when I try to use a browser (whichever), sometimes when I visit a page, it wont load. Only the white screen remains, or I can see the title, still nothing loads. When I refresh again, then it loads. What can it be?

Comment: no proxy is set

Comment: What browser are you using? What version?

Comment: Try an ipconfig /flushdns. Check your network connection status for dropped packets.

And indeed, try different browsers.

Comment: I use both Firefox and IExplorer. Same result

Comment: "Check your network connection status for dropped packets" where is this?

Comment: update: Firefox: infinitive loading. IExplorer: "connection error"